# How to pass function address to Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline-assembly, cortex-m

With gcc/clang for ARM cortex M, is there a way to pass a function address as a constant in Assembler Instructions with C Expression Operands ? More precisely I'd like to load R12 with function address (stored in the memory):
`ldr R12, =func`
within a C function, foe example like this one

```
// __attribute__((naked)) 
int loader(int fn)
{
__asm ("ldr R12, =%0"::??? (fn):"r12");
// ... then  SVC #0, and the R0 is the return value 
}
```

The question is what exactly I have to put for the Input Operand?

EDIT:
Thanks for the comments!
Actually I need to re-implement the KEIL's `__svc_indirect(0)` which loads R12 with function address and passes up to four arguments in R0..R3 (see [__svc_indirect](https://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/armcc/armcc_chr1359124970017.htm)

Comment: Is there some reason you don't just ask for the function address in a register in the first place?  Like `(void*)fn` to case your `int` to a pointer, or just ask for the int in a register, like `"r"(fn)`.  You can use `register int fn asm("r12")` to make the "r" constraint pick r12.  How do you want your code to compile?  Like you want this to inline into some caller so `int fn` can be a link-time constant that the compiler can embed into an instruction via a symbol name?  But naked functions can't inline.

Comment: Note that `naked` functions can't safely use Extended Asm, only Basic (no constraints/operands).  And they need to manually return (e.g. end with `bx lr`)  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-Function-Attributes.html#index-naked-function-attribute_002c-ARM

Comment: non-bitchy function returning `int` value, should place something into `r0` register...

Comment: @peter-cordes,  I need to re-implement the KEIL's __svc_indirect(0) which loads R12 with function address and passes up to four arguments in R0..R3

Comment: Ok, then you should use an `"r"` constraint to have GCC do the `ldr` for you (with a `register ... asm("r12")` variable).   And don't make a `naked` function; that's basically equivalent to using a separate `.s` file, except for name mangling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an `i` constraint and manually prepend the `=` character:

```
__asm ("ldr r12, =%0" :: "i"(fn) : "r12");
```

Note that the inline assembly statement is still incorrect for other reasons, some of which were outlined in the comments on your question.  Also consider using a register-constrainted variable for this sort of thing:

```
register int fn asm("r12");
__asm ("" :: "r"(fn));
```